How to paste word documents with internal bookmarks into a new document, while keeping the bookmarks linked internally
I have generated multiple word documents from a tool, that each contain dozens to hundreds of internal bookmarks. I want to then paste each of these documents into a different document. The issue is, once pasted, the bookmarks link to the original document, rather than the internal location. Also, since the tool reuses the same bookmark names for each output, even if I could find a way to keep the bookmarks to reference internally (some of the smaller docs will paste into a clean word doc and keep internal refernces), all of the documents pasted after incorrectly hyperlink to bookmarks from the first document.
Is there any way, through vba, or other to:

remove the external file link from the bookmark, leaving only the internal link
group rename all of the bookmarks in a document so when pasted they do not clash with existing links

Manually changing 1000s of link not an option :)
Thanks!

Are you sure these are actual bookmarks? The thing is that Word bookmarks do not link to anything. References to bookmarks  e.g. fields that look like { mybookmarkname } or { REF mybookmarkname } don't have a facility to link to bookmarks in other documents either. The usual way Word can do that is using either a { LINK } field or an { INCLUDETEXT } field. If your tool is creating those, then yes, it should be possible to do something in VBA...

Try simply using an IncludeText field to insert the document rather than copy and paste. I could not do what you are trying to do and expect that any potential solution will be rather complex. http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html
